# Why is my date not being set correctly to 30 days in the future?

Tags: java, date

I have the following:

```
    Date now = new Date();
    Date futureDate = new Date(now.getYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDay() + 30);
```

I want to set the future date value to be 30 days in the future, based on the current date (now).

When I debug this, now is the correct date, and the futureDate is:

```
Sat Jan 05 00:00:00 EST 2013
```

Today's date, the value of now is: Sat Dec 29 17:31:58 EST 2012.

This doesn't make sense to me?

I'm using util.Date.

Comment: From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html: the `Date(int year, int month, int day)` constructor is deprecated. Use `Date(long date)`.

Comment: Yeah, and that was several versions ago.

Comment: that explains why Intellij is putting lines through the parameters :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because `getDay()` returns day of the week, not day of the month.

So your

```
now.getDay() + 30
```

becomes Saturday + 30 = 6 + 30 = 36th December = 5th January

A quick fix would be to replace your code with:

```
now.getDate() + 30
```

---

But as others already suggest, `java.util.Date` is kind of deprecated. And you should use `Calendar.add()`. So your code would become something like:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, +30);
```

Comment: Is there a more accurate way of subtracting a month?  (since months can be 29,30 or 31 days).

Comment: Subtracting or adding? And yes, you can use `cal.add(Calendar.MONTH, +1);`

Answer (score 4):

You should use Calendar and its method [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html).add

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Date, you'll see working with adding days is all kinds of deprecated:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html

Use `new Date(now.getTime() + (MILLISECONDS_IN_DAY * 30))` instead. Or if you're not stuck with Date, use Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is that constructor deprecated, it only accepts valid days (1-31).

try using java.util.Calendar instead.

Answer (score 0):

`Date` is not supposed to be used for such calculations.

Have a look at [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) which is exelent for such things.